# Passing aspx page via Stream

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, wcf

I have an aspx page that needs to be an embedded resource for a WCF project. An interfacing service serves the aspx/html/js files to the web browser via a Stream object. The problem I am having is getting the aspx page to display properly. I have tried setting the content type to "text/html", but when I do this, I get the following at the top of the page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="Services.Interface.Views.WebForm" %>
```

Which is the first line of Index.aspx.
Since it's being served as an html file, the aspx "stuff" is ignored, I guess.

I've also tried setting the content type to "application/xhtml+xm" as some have suggested, but I get an error that says:

```
 This page contains the following errors:
 error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name
 Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

I have tried taking out the ASP stuff from Index.aspx and changing it to an HTML file, and it works, but I need the ASP capabilities for accessing some settings in Web.config.

Is there a proper content type for aspx pages that I'm not aware of, or is something else going wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't do that.  You can't use the same file as both ASPX and HTML.

Comment: Switch to Razor, so that you can run the Razor engine from your WCF service and be consistent.